# How to add a specific timer to a batch logger

Tags: batch-file, logging

I am currently using a batch file to log data on a com port.
The command I have is this:

```
@echo off

mode COM5 

BAUD=9600 PARITY=n DATA=8

echo d >COM5

COPY COM5 data.txt
```

And the data appears as this, at a rate of 1Hz:

```
: 000003 000025-000001-000024 000015 094978U

: 000003 000025-000001-000024 000016 094978U
```

The resulting text file is then run through an extract tool which then plots graphs and analyses the deviation between the numbers.
The problem is, is that the extract tool only works if the data appears as this:

```
00000000.003 :-000012 000010-000006 000081 000109 179549U

00000000.039 :-000012 000010-000006 000080 000109 179549U
```

the numbers before the colon is a timer of some sort, how can I add this to my batch file in order for it to log in the format that works with the extract tool?

Comment: The two sets of data appear unrelated. Please explain the required transformation.